# passing variable to email recipient field in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass a variable from a dropdown list to an email recipient.
 This is the script for the dropdown list:

```
$objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,90) 
$objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objListBox.Height = 80

[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Rod@tafe.gov.au")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("James@msn.com")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Josh@abc.net")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Logan@cba.com")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("George@tafe.gov.nsw")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Nic@someone.com")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("Shit@box.com")

$ourForm.Controls.Add($objListBox) 

$ourForm.Topmost = $True

$ourForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
$mailto
```

This is the script to send the Email:

```
send-mailmessage -To '$MailTo' -From 'arivergod@msn.com' `
                 -Body 'ItIsDone, He is sleeping with the Fish' `
                 -Subject 'Contract' -SMTP 'arivergod@msn.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ShowDialog() call to this:

```
if ($objForm.ShowDialog() -eq [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $mailto = $objListBox.SelectedValue
}
```

Also you can't single quote around a variable e.g. `'$mailTo'`. Single quotes in PowerShell is like verbatim strings in C#.  What gets passed as the value for the To parameter is literally `$MailTo`.  Change to this:

```
 send-mailmessage -To $mailTo -From arivergod@msn.com `
                  -Body 'ItIsDone, He is sleeping with the Fish' `
                  -Subject Contract -SMTP arivergod@msn.com
```

Also note that PowerShell will typically process arguments as strings by default unless they start with $ @ ( , ; or {.  If you have spaces, embedded quotes or semicolon in a string argument, you would also need to quote it.

Comment: Well yeah, it is using single quotes around the Body argument. `$()` doesn't work inside single quotes. Have a look at the help topic about_Quoting_Rules.